# How to populate a custom table data in a dropdown field within adminhtml -> UIComponent ->form.xml

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

```
<field name="agent" sortOrder="170" >
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object"></item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Module</item>
        <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Test</item>
        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">Module</item>
    </item>
</argument>
</field>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Check Cms module example](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Cms/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_page_form.xml#L217). Your options tag object is empty. Add class following way:

```
<item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Cms\Model\Page\Source\PageLayout</item>
```

And [check here how create class as an example](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Cms/Model/Page/Source/PageLayout.php). Add your option class inside **toOptionArray** method. Ex:

```
/**
 * Get options
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function toOptionArray()
{
    if ($this->options !== null) {
        return $this->options;
    }

    $configOptions = $this->pageLayoutBuilder->getPageLayoutsConfig()->getOptions();
    $options = [];
    foreach ($configOptions as $key => $value) {
        $options[] = [
            'label' => $value,
            'value' => $key,
        ];
    }
    $this->options = $options;

    return $this->options;
}
```